# nginx on Ubuntu with froxlor config

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, plesk

I installed nginx on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, first it said that everything is working well but after I configured as given in froxlor config it no longer works. Unfortunately I don't know why. Maybe could you help me. This is the IP which should be reached: http://united-craft.com

Thanks for your help.

Btw: How to enable nginx start on server start/boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://united-craft.com

This host is working under nginx already.

> How to enable nginx start on server start/boot?

You should write init start/stop script, place it in /etc/init.d/ and create symlinks in corresponding folders of run level in /etc/rc.d/  check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)

Or install nginx with package manager.

Or install/upgrade to Plesk 11.5, it has nginx support and do the dirty work for you.

Comment: I run Plesk 11.5 but unfortunately I don't get how to enable nginx support. However, I assume there are many better management systems like ajenti because you can update more easy and thus safe (mostly) resources. What do you think?

Comment: it depends on how much sites you have and is there need to provide access to sites management for other people. I've manage my 6 sites by myself without any management system.

Comment: In Plesk 11.5 you can start/enable nginx in Tools & Settings > Services Management(nginx should be installed in Parallels Installer first). It's automatically switch apache to another port and setup nginx as front-end.